# How to spawn subthreads from threads in openMP (C++)

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

I am trying to build a tree with a fixed number of children as well as a fixed depth. I do not fully understand the underlying mechanics of openMP. Tree construction begins upon calling `build(root_node, 0)`. Now let's suppose that `maxDepth` is given an arbitrary number and that `maxChildren` is equal to `n`. When `build(root_node, 0)` is called, `n` threads are launched. I was under the impression that each of these `n` threads would create `n` threads. However, careful observation of `top` revealed that there are never more than `n` threads. I can saturate my cores only when `maxChildren` is equal or higher than the number of cores I have. It seems that the `parallel` blocks in subsequent levels in the recursion have no effet, limiting the number of available threads for subsequent use to what was needed in the initial call to `build`.

Why does it behave this way? Has the recursion any part in this? And most importantly, what can I do to remedy this? Thanks in advance.

```
void
build(Node* pNode, unsigned int depth)
{
    if (depth >= maxDepth)
        return;
    std::list<Node*> children;
    std::list<Node*>::iterator it;
    // This loop cannot be parallelized because each call to select_next_node
    // is dependent on the previous one
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < maxChildren; ++i)
    {
        Node* const p_candidate_node = select_next_node(...);
        if (is_valid(p_candidate_node))
            children.push_back(p_candidate_node);
    }

    #pragma omp parallel private(it)
    for (it = children.begin(); it != children.end(); ++it)
    #pragma omp single nowait
        build(*it, depth + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested parallelism is disabled by default in almost all OpenMP run-times. You should explicitly enable it by one of those two methods:

- call `omp_set_nested(1);`
- set environment variable `OMP_NESTED` to `TRUE`

Nested parallelism might not be what you want in that case. The number of threads could grow very fast and consume lots of system resources. You should rather use OpenMP tasks. They should be supported by all OpenMP 3.0 compliant compilers.

Comment: Enabling nested parallelism did indeed consume too many resources, I keep getting "Thread creation failed: Resource temporarily unavailable" errors with `maxDepth = 10` and `maxChildren = 2`. Thank you once more for your wisdom!

Comment: Is there a way to put restrictions as to the maximum number of threads that can be spawned without explicitly setting environment variables?

Comment: You can specify the maximum number of threads by setting the `OMP_NUM_THREADS` environment variable. Its value is a comma separated list of positive numbers that specify the number of threads to use at each nested level, e.g. `export OMP_NUM_THREADS=4,2,2` means 4 threads at the base level and then up to 2 threads for the first and the second nested level.

Comment: Thank you! I'll +1 when I get enough reputation to do so.